# Bootstrap 3 2 row menu showing scroll bars

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a two row bootstrap 3 men.  When it collapses It's showing both vertical and horizontal scroll bars.  Any ideas or way I can get rid of them.  I have the menu up at  **shipfms.com/1html.html**  A working exaplne wirtten in Word Press is here  http://shipfms.btddev.com/     The code is below My first time posting here. Hope I did it correctly

Thanks

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
 rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
```

family=Lato:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=latin,latin-ext' type='text/css' media='all' />

```
                 <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>

                <asp:Label ID="lblcookie" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

            </div>

            <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                <div class="row" style="background-color: #064871;">
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                        <i class="material-icons" style="padding-left: 100px; font-size: medium; color: white;">phone</i>
                        <span id="number" style="color: white; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif; font-size: small;">865-922-7491</span>
                        <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: medium; color: white;">&nbsp;email</i>
                        <a id="email" href="mailto:info@shipfms.com" style="text-decoration: none;">
                            <span style="color: white; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;">info@shipfms.com</span></a>

                    </div>


                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-right: 25px; margin-right: 50px;">
                        <li style="color: white; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;"><a href="#"><span style="color: white;">Login&nbsp;</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span style="color: white; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;">Profile</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span style="color: white; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;">Messages</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span style="color: white; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;">Sign Up</span></a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div class="row" style="background-color: white;">
                    <div class="col-md-3 container-fluid img-fluid " style="float: left; background-color: white;">
                        <img src="images/FMS_Logo_websiteHeadersmaller.jpg" alt="Freight Management Systems" class="img-fluid " />

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-7 navbar-right " style="height: 85px; margin-right: 50px;">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="text-align: left; padding-top: 20px;">
                            <!--    <li>&nbsp;</li>   -->
                            <li>&nbsp;</li>
                            <li>&nbsp;</li>
                            <li>&nbsp;</li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;">Shipping Services</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;">Freight Tips</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;">About US</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;">Contacts</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;">Blogs</span></a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

I have found both the errors causing this. For the downward scroll it is the code below:

```
<div class="col-lg-7 navbar-right " style="height: 85px; margin-right: 50px;">
```

By defining a height you are in turn fixing an element. This will stop BS from flowing the way it normally would.

The second issue and the reason as to why the horizontal scroll is appearing is because you are defining a row on the first block with no cols.

```
<div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #064871;">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-top: 5px;">
```

The way BS works is that the cols contradict the gutters on the rows so if you arent going to use cols there is no need for a row!

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Great. Thanks I was able to get rid of the vertical scroll bar by removing the height in the style tag.  

I've tried wrapping the <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-top: 5px;">   in a DIV with col's every which way but am having no success getting rid of the horizontal scroll bar.  Any help, example or directions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Remove the row. That should fix the problem :)

Comment: Humm It didn't, oh well  I may experiment some more down the road.  Thanks You :)